# Magento: want catalog/layer/view result in catalog/category/view

Tags: php, magento, filter

I get all the products as usual by using  `<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml()?>`

But the filters section stays outside the `category/view.phtml` 
I have changed the `catelog.xml` like below:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>  
.
.
.
```

How do I show the price range in `layer/view.phtml` in my `catalog/category/view` block.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean left panel price range filter . Just check if your category is set with is Anchor yes. As its Magento default features you no need to customized anything.

Comment: Yes its showing the result in the page but not inside the category/view.phtml block after activating template path hints 'on' and so as I couldn't place it under the category/view.phtml file where I want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know magento overriding concept and you are modifying everything by overriding. So please use this under reference content rather than left.

Answer (score 0):

Catalog Category (Anchor)enter image description herebel>
page/2columns-left.phtml
if its doesn't work then please try to put with catalog_category_default tag

Comment: Please follow my last comment . its working fine for me. Filter will come up under product listing page

Comment: Dont just put your answer comments as new answers kindly ..its very difficult to find out which one you are using...as Stackoverflow shows the last commented post.